# another ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I am new to Java and especially to iterating through lists and modifying it's elements. I went through dozens of similar questions, but after many tries nothing worked. 
In the following code sample an exceptions is thrown. It is not related to concurrent thread as I only have one thread. Netbeans output sais that the exception occurs in line 5(CustomerData customer = i.next();) :

```
CustomerData tempCustomer = new CustomerData("",tagID,0);
tempCustomer.setName(name);
tempCustomer.setSize(size);
for(ListIterator<CustomerData> i = customers.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); )
{
    CustomerData customer = i.next();
    if(customer.getTagID().contains(tagID))
    {
        Object[] options = {"overwrite", "do not overwrite"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, 
                                            "TagID already exists. overwrite?", 
                                            "?", 
                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                            null, 
                                            options, 
                                            rootPane);
       if ( n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION ){
           i.set(tempCustomer); 
       }
    }
    else{
        addCustomer();
    }
}
```

The whole code is only supposed to check if the element has matching tagID and if it does, replace two values (name and size) in it. Initially I tried to use `setName()` and `setSize()` inside the for loop on the element, but after it didn't work and after reading other related questions, I assigned the values to temporary object before the loop and the used the iterator's set method to replace current element. But still no success and it even seems it never gets that far because the exception comes after line 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is presumably that this line:

```
        addCustomer();
```

is trying to modify `customers` while you're in the middle of iterating over it. This isn't allowed.

And anyway, it seems like a logic error: presumably you want to call `addCustomer` only once, after the loop, if *no* customer had the right `tagID`, but your current code tries to call `addCustomer` for *each* customer with with the wrong `tagID`. So you need to use a `boolean` variable during the loop to keep track of whether any customer matched, and then, after the loop, call `addCustomer` if appropriate.

Comment: Ah! You are right. I was looking at the if-part all the time and not at the else-part with the function. Now I replaced the `addCustomer()` with `i.add` and it works... a fresh look at the code does miracles. Plus, NetBeans confused me by telling that the exception occurs in line 5. I guess it counts the whole if-else statement as wrong. All three answers are right, and those that I read before asking the question. I will mark yours as right for the advice with the logic error. Will get on that next. Thank you and everyone!

Answer (score 0):

ConcurentModificationException does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread.

In your case the problem might be in following (guessing by addCustomer method): you are getting iterator of collection and then modifiying this collection. Because collection is modified, iterator becomes invalid and exception is thrown.

My suggestion will be create temproray list of customers which will you will append to your original customer list, when your iteration finished.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over
>   the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception.

I guess it is occurring after a call to `addCustomer()` which modifies the `customers` object. You can either hold the newly added objects in a different collection until end of the loop or break out of the loop and restart after adding.